# Map apps- know where I will be on route at specific time?

Tags: planning, driving, maps, solo-travel

Is there an app that will tell me what city I will be in at a given time along my route?

Eg, if I leave NY at 2am to drive to Detroit, and the estimated total commute time is 10 hours, what city will I be in at 8am?

Obviously I can roughly estimate this manually ... But is there an app that would do this more accurately? I haven't seen this feature in Google Maps or Waze.

Thanks!

Comment: Google maps provides a detailed route option as an option. This shows distances between each "waypoint" and time at each point. If you change your route you can recalculate from where you are if you have internet access.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to take a turn or follow a (different) particular road often, you can calculate your route using [Via Michelin](http://www.viamichelin.com/) and look at the details. It will say how long you'll have been driving already at every action/turn you'll have to take. Then you only have to add that time to the time you will leave and look into the details where you'll be at that time.

If your trip doesn't generate enough details, it's maybe too hard to tell what city you'll be in. But I hope it will suffice, if nothing better pops up.