# Road trip distance/driving time planning

Tags: usa, planning, road-trips, maps

I am planning a cross country, point-to-point road trip that will total about 26 hours of driving.  The purpose of this trip is not sight seeing, but just to get from point A to point B.

I can plug my start and finish destinations into google and get a nice map with the shortest route and the total drive time duration.  But for better planning of breaks along the way etc what would really help is to be able to see how the accumulated drive time varies across the span of the trip.  EG what I want is something like one of these:

- See ticks or coloration along the route that indicate (say for example) 1, 2, 4 or 8 hours of drive time.
- Drop pins on the route (that I can move around) and directly see the drive time duration between them
- Specify the number of hours driving per leg that I want to endure.

As per the comment on [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/48367/6188) from 2015 I could manually set waypoints in google maps and then read through the detailed directions in order to glean the durations between said waypoints.  But that seems so 4 years ago (and a lot of work - especially as it is very easy to add a waypoint that isn't on the direct route).  And I looked at the Michelin web site in the answer and that seems to want a whole lot of information from me that I was not prepared to share.

Is there a better alternative in 2019?

Comment: Where do you want to make stops? Do you want to divide the 26 hours into equal segments (e.g. to switch between 3 drivers) or do you want to go to some place to sleep (a hotel / motel / etc.)?

Comment: @JJJ I want to plan to make stops.  But I want to be able to balance the drive legs so that my stops don't end up in either the middle of nowhere or the middle of a humongous city - which will require some interactive tweaking.

Comment: If your on the interstate there are plenty of rest stops to use the bathroom.  If your just traveling to go from point A to B then most likely your gas gauge will determine when you stop. Fuel consumption is kind of tricky to plan for (hills, traffic tie ups, 80mph speeds on some roads).  It would be best to play it by gauge after you have your route picked.  If your in the west don't let your gas gauge get bellow 1/2 full.  Towns are far apart.

Comment: @PeterM I can't see a problem with the viamichelin-website. You can add a lot of information there, but it's optional and not required

Answer (score 1):

You can sort of do this in Google Maps now, though it's probably not quite as automatic as you might like.

Consider this [26 hour drive from Bangor, ME to Miami, FL](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Bangor,+Maine+04401,+USA/Miami,+Florida,+USA/@34.9831742,-84.225102,5z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x4cae4b46101129bd:0x4d0918b0a7af7677!2m2!1d-68.7712257!2d44.8016128!1m5!1m1!1s0x88d9b0a20ec8c111:0xff96f271ddad4f65!2m2!1d-80.1917902!2d25.7616798!3e0):

[image: Bangor, ME to Miami, FL]

To add a waypoint, I'm going to click the ⊕, and then drag the new waypoint to the center of the list:

[image: Bangor, ME to blank to Miami, FL]

Then I click in the text field, and either type in a city or click on the map. Here, I will guess the halfway point and type in Richmond, VA and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I first thought of Washington, but it's probably the sort of big city you'd rather drive through than stop in. I end up with [this three point set of directions](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Bangor,+Maine+04401,+USA/Richmond,+Virginia,+USA/Miami,+Florida,+USA/@34.9831742,-84.225102,5z/am=t/data=!4m20!4m19!1m5!1m1!1s0x4cae4b46101129bd:0x4d0918b0a7af7677!2m2!1d-68.7712257!2d44.8016128!1m5!1m1!1s0x89b111095799c9ed:0xbfd83e6de2423cc5!2m2!1d-77.4360481!2d37.5407246!1m5!1m1!1s0x88d9b0a20ec8c111:0xff96f271ddad4f65!2m2!1d-80.1917902!2d25.7616798!3e0):

[image: Bangor, ME to Richmond, VA to Miami, FL]

Here, if I click Details, it will show me separate travel times for each segment.

[image: Directions details]

Once you have a waypoint, you can drag it around to change your route, and click Details again to see the new travel routes and times.

[image: Drag waypoint to change route]

It's not perfect, but perhaps it's good enough?

Comment: I know that I can do that (it was also referenced in that other question)  I'm looking for something more visual and more interactive.

Comment: Once you have the waypoint showing on the map, you can drag it around.

Comment: And I have to keep gleaning the data from the details.

Comment: Like I said, it's not exactly what you want, as you do have to do lots of extra clicking to get the info you want to see, but I don't think anything better exists right now.

Comment: That was the question - does anything better exist?  What you are suggesting is already mentioned in my question as what I don't want to do.

Comment: I have just been playing around with this and noted two things:  1) You can right-click on Google maps in order to add a destination.  2) Google limits the number of stops between start and end to 8 - only enough to cover a third of my trip.

Comment: @PeterM If you really want 24 waypoints, I suspect you are extremely overthinking your trip. Whatever planning you do, it's all going to go out the window as soon as you hit the road. You'll have to be ready to deal with the unexpected: traffic, construction, accidents, whatever.

Comment: I was wanting 2 hour waypoints as I am going to be transporting animals and need to plan some regular breaks in order to ensure that they are doing well.  I meant to say 2/3 instead of 1/3 in my previous comment  but realized after the 5 minute mark.    And yes I am away of traffic.  But I don't think that seeing a trip broken down into 1 hour segments is over thinking it.

Comment: @PeterM OK, it makes more sense now. But your question did not mention transporting animals; if it had, then you might have been able to get some useful information from other people who have traveled with animals. This is quite a bit different than your typical road trip.

Comment: Personally I don't think that the animals part is germane to what I wanted - a way to easily segment a trip into sections

Answer (score 1):

Also maybe not a perfect solution for your usecase, but maybe better than Google Maps: https://roadtrippers.com/
This allows you to create a route and add intermediate stops on an interactive map. The downside is (since that tool is mainly targeting sightseeing road trips), that you have to select POIs for your stops, like restaurants, hotels etc. You cannot just put a marker on any arbitrary location. But it at least shows directly the times and distances for each sub segment in the trip overview.

Another tool which i used to plan my last roadtrip: https://trips.furkot.com/
It can split the tour into daily chunks, with suggestions where to stay overnight so that it fits the plan etc.

Comment: This is definitely better than google for what I want (as the segment times are more apparent), but still much the same :(

Comment: Added an edit with another tool, that might fit the requirement better.